# TSP in Python: Importing a .csv-file in code for randomized data points

Tags: python, traveling-salesman

im quite the noob when it comes to coding.
I am currently trying to code a solution for a traveling salesman problem. I already found functioning code for a set of random values (as seen below or in https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/TSP.ipynb#Random-Sets-of-Cities). Now i want to use data in a .csv file that i have created, containing data of cities in a coordinate system (x and y values). However i cannot figure out what exactly i have to change in the code.

I tried changing the definition of the Cities() function into `return frozenset(City() for row in csv.reader(staedtekoordinaten.csv, delimiter=";")` but this does not work either.

It is probably quite the stupid question, but i would highly appreciate if someone could help me... Thanks in advance!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import time
import itertools
import urllib
import csv
import functools
from statistics import mean, stdev


def alle_touren_tsp(cities):
    # Erstelle eine Auflistung aller möglichen auszuführenden Touren. Aus dieser Liste
    # kann später eine Auswahl per "min" Funktion getroffen werden, die die kürzeste Route darstellt.
    return minimale_tour(alle_touren(cities))


def minimale_tour(tours):
    # Definiere Funktion zur Auswahl der kürzesten Tour.
    return min(tours, key=laenge_tour)  # aus der Sammlung "touren" minimiere ELement "distanz_tour"


#Verbesserung - Redundante Touren werden vermieden (reduziert Rechenaufwand)
def alle_touren(cities):
    # Gibt List mit Touren aus mit Permutation von Städten, alle permutationen starten jedoch mit
    # derselben Stadt (verhindert Redundanzen)
    start = first(cities)
    return [[start] + Tour(rest)
            for rest in itertools.permutations(cities - {start})]

def first(collection):
    #Iteration über die collection, Ausgabe des jeweils ersten Elements
    return next(iter(collection))

Tour = list  # Tours are implemented as lists of cities


def laenge_tour(tour):
    # Gesamtsumme einer Tour.
    # Addiert die gelaufenen Teildistanzen zwischen zwei Datenpunkten (= locations)
    return sum(distance(tour[i], tour[i - 1])  # für i=0 wird i-1 der letzte Datenpunkt
               for i in range(len(tour)))
    # Für alle Elemente in tour (Anzahl = len(tour)) wird die Distanz von der vorherigen Location (i-1)
    # zur aktuellen (i) summiert)


# Lösung mit Subclass von Complex - Jeder Datenpunkt (also jeder Ort) wird mit zwei Koordinaten gespeichert,
# der Einfachheit halber im komplexen Zahlenraum (dort hat jeder Punkt generell zwei Koordinaten)
class Datenpunkt(complex):
    x = property(lambda p: p.real)
    y = property(lambda p: p.imag)


City = Datenpunkt


def distance(A, B):
    # Definiert die Distanz "zu laufende Länge" zwischen den Punkten A und B => Euklidische Distanz
    return abs(A - B)


# Testdatenpunkt: Randomized Cities mit Seed 42
def Cities(n, width=900, height=600, seed=42):
    # Set aus n Datenpunkten mit randomized Koordinaten, dargestellt in width x height (900x600 weil Python-Standard)
    random.seed(seed * n)
    return frozenset(City(random.randrange(width), random.randrange(height))
                     # frozenset, damit kein Algorithmus einfach Datenpunkte löscht
                     # (i. S. v. der kürzeste Weg wäre, erst gar keinen Weg zu laufen)
                     for c in range(n))

alle_touren_tsp(Cities(8))

def plot_tour(tour):
    # "Plot the cities as circles and the tour as lines between them."
    plot_lines(list(tour) + [tour[0]])


def plot_lines(points, style='bo-'):
    # "Plot lines to connect a series of points."
    plt.plot([p.x for p in points], [p.y for p in points], style)
    plt.axis('scaled');
    plt.axis('off')


plot_tour(alle_touren_tsp(Cities(8)))


def plot_tsp(algorithm, cities):
    # "Apply a TSP algorithm to cities, plot the resulting tour, and print information."
    # Find the solution and time how long it takes
    t0 = time.process_time()
    tour = algorithm(cities)
    t1 = time.process_time()
    assert valid_tour(tour, cities)
    plot_tour(tour);
    plt.show()
    print("{} city tour with length {:.1f} in {:.3f} secs for {}"
          .format(len(tour), laenge_tour(tour), t1 - t0, algorithm.__name__))


def valid_tour(tour, cities):
    # "Is tour a valid tour for these cities?"
    return set(tour) == set(cities) and len(tour) == len(cities)


plot_tsp(alle_touren_tsp, Cities(8))
```

As for the new code (if I understood the remarks correctly:

```
import csv


# Lösung mit Subclass von Complex - Jeder Datenpunkt (also jeder Ort) wird mit zwei Koordinaten gespeichert,
# der Einfachheit halber im komplexen Zahlenraum (dort hat jeder Punkt generell zwei Koordinaten)
class Datenpunkt(complex):
    x = property(lambda p: p.real)
    y = property(lambda p: p.imag)


class City(Datenpunkt):

    # this is a subclass of `complex` which sets itself up in `__new__`
    def __new__(cls, x, y, name):
        self = super().__new__(cls, float(x), float(y))
        self.name = name
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(super().__str__(), self.name)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

    @classmethod
    def from_csv(cls, row):
        """Create class from CSV row. Row is assumed to be a collection with
        index 0 and 1 being the coordinates of interest."""
        return cls(*row[0:3])


def Cities(filename):
    with open(filename, newline='') as fp:
        return frozenset(City.from_csv(row) for row in csv.reader(fp, delimiter=";"))
print(Cities("testfile.csv"))
```

This gives the errors:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "filepath/Test.py", line 35, in <module>
  print(Cities("testfile.csv"))

File "filepath/Test.py", line 34, in Cities
  return frozenset(City.from_csv(row) for row in csv.reader(fp, 
delimiter=";"))

File "filepath/Test.py", line 34, in <genexpr>
  return frozenset(City.from_csv(row) for row in csv.reader(fp, 
delimiter=";"))

File "filepath/Test.py", line 29, in from_csv
  return cls(*row[0:3])

File "filepath/Test.py", line 15, in __new__
  self = super().__new__(cls, float(x), float(y))

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ï»¿x'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The printed lines according to your idea are:

```
b'\xef\xbb\xbfx;y;name\r\n'b'0;0;Duisburg\r\n'
b'455,56;120,87;Berlin\r\n'
b'218,86;235,59;Hamburg\r\n'
b'345,6;-366,75;Muenchen\r\n'
b'13,97;-55,24;Koeln\r\n'
b'135,12;-147,2;Frankfurt\r\n'
b'190,25;-13,17;Kassel\r\n'
b'297,02;-51,3;Erfurt\r\n
```

Comment: What does the CSV file look like?

Comment: 3 coloumns, the first two contain the x and y value respectively, the third contains the name of the city. 9 rows in total, the first of which is filled with headlines

Comment: Do you want to include name with the City class? Personal ignorance here, is expressing coordinates as a single complex number a normal thing? Inheriting from complex, int and other fundamental types can be a challenge.

Comment: Including the city names would be nice, but its not mandatory by any means.
When I found the code i have posted i was also a little dumbfounded by the complex number thing. i have never seen that before, but because i dont really have enough knowledge to find another solution, i decided to roll with it

Answer (score 0):

You can make `City` inherit from `Datenpunkt` and add whatever specializations you want there. Since complex numbers initialize themselves in the `__new__` method, you have to implement one youself if your object construction parameters are different than `complex`. I decided to add city name plus allow coordinates as strings as an example of what you can do.

I also added a class method that knows the csv row format. You could argue that its a rather narrow specialization of `City` and that this factory should be an external function instead, but, hey, I did it anyway just to show the option.

This example runs and you and add it to your code as you see fit.

```
import csv

# Lösung mit Subclass von Complex - Jeder Datenpunkt (also jeder Ort) wird mit zwei Koordinaten gespeichert,
# der Einfachheit halber im komplexen Zahlenraum (dort hat jeder Punkt generell zwei Koordinaten)
class Datenpunkt(complex):
    x = property(lambda p: p.real)
    y = property(lambda p: p.imag)

class City(Datenpunkt):

    # this is a subclass of `complex` which sets itself up in `__new__`
    def __new__(cls, x, y, name):
        self = super().__new__(cls, float(x), float(y))
        self.name = name
        return self
        
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(super().__str__(), self.name)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

    @classmethod
    def from_csv(cls, row):
        """Create class from CSV row. Row is assumed to be a collection with
        index 0 and 1 being the coordinates of interest."""
        return cls(*row[0:3])
        

def Cities(filename):
    with open(filename, newline='') as fp:
        return frozenset(City.from_csv(row) for row in csv.reader(fp, delimiter=";"))


# test
print(City.from_csv(["111", "222", "Far City"]))
open('testcities.csv', 'w').write("""\
111;222;Far City
4.55;66;Near City
""")

cities = Cities('testcities.csv')
print(cities)
for city in cities:
    print("{}: {}, {}".format(city.name, city.x, city.y))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! However, i am still quite lost.. I got rid of ```City = Datenpunkt``` and the definition of the Cities function. Instead i added your code. I also defined ```filename``` to be corresponding to my file and added it to the three different sectors in which the ```Cities``` function is called. It gives me multiple errors inclidung "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ï»¿x' ". I am probably making some rookie mistakes again, i have never programmed anything outside the very basic stuff before.

Comment: You could narrow the problem down by trying your csv files with my test code. Remove my tests and instead print each filename as you call `Cities(filename)`. Now you know the offending file and you could post it (or a small sample that also fails) in your original question. This may be a problem with the file's character encoding, so reading and printing it in binary mode to post here may help. (open(filename, 'rb').read())`.

Comment: Added the new code to the inital question. I re-created the same file again manually and also took care of some good old german "umlauts" that were existing. Still having the same issues

Comment: The CSV file causing the problem would help. There seems to be 2 problems: 1) the CSV file encoding - you could see what `sys.getdefaultencoding()` says and compare that with that with the CSV encoding (could be that your default encoding is 'latin-1' but the CSV itself is utf-8 for instance). 2) it seems like its not "x;y;name" as assumed here. It is still critical to post what this CSV is. You say you fixed the umlats.... you could find a file with umlates, figure out a few umlatey lines and post their binary representation here.

Comment: Lets say that lines 3-6 in file "foo.csv" have non-ascii characters. You could do `for line in open("foo.csv", "rb").readlines()[3:7]: print(line)`. That would be a good bit of data.

Comment: default encoding according to PyCharm is utf-8, .csv encoding is also utf-8. I have added the printed lines to the original question.
Even if I open the file with the editor, i get the clean data withouth any issues.